# Difference between assert and asserta - PROLOG

Tags: prolog

I am really not clear about the difference between assert and asserta, as when I was trying to make a fibonacci program in linear time. Asserta worked really fast whereas assert gave me an error.

Can some one explain why asserta is better than assert in some cases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In not a question of being better. The `assert/1` predicate is legacy and nowadays usually an alias to the `assertz/1` predicate. The difference between the `asserta/1` and `assertz/1` predicates is that the first asserts a clause  as the first one for a dynamic predicate while the second asserts a clause as the last one for a dynamic predicate.

Comment: the intention of the naming could be to see the clauses of a predicate as a ordered list A to Z like an ordered alphabet, and then assert"A" is prepending, and assert"Z" is appending additional clauses to that list (dynamic predicate)?